# Load UITableViewCell images using parsing

Tags: ios, parsing, uitableview, uiimageview

I followed a tutorial of JSON parsing and modified my rss feed to post featured image in a tag if xxxxxxxx and now i need to assign each image link to it's corresponding row next to it's title.

I saved links in a nsmutablestring and used it's url to assign it to my image like this

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"thumbnail"]]]];
```

but it's not working , this is the only piece of my application left, please help me through it

Here is my code

```
#import "APPMasterViewController.h"
#import "APPDetailViewController.h"

@interface APPMasterViewController () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSMutableString *thumbnail;
    NSString *element;

}
@end

@implementation APPMasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icuore.ly/feed"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"thumbnail"]]]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
      thumbnail = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:thumbnail forKey:@"thumbnail"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"thumbnail"]) {
        [thumbnail appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the problem? it is not getting image from url? or it is not setting it to cell?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your image isn't showing is because your image hasn't finished downloading before `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. Remember this method is responsible for displaying the cells of your `UITableView`. When setting your cells with data from the Internet, it's important to reload the data of your `UITableView` after it finishes downloading. I recommend accomplishing this using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to download your image as it has delegates that handle download updates. For example, one of these delegates is:

```
URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:
```

Once this delegate is implemented, it will be called after your session download has finished. Hypothetically, in the said delegate, you would update your image view and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: i'm sorry , i'm still new to Objective-C , could you help me finish the code , i made some progress using the "SDWebImage" framework like this : [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"thumbnail"]]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icuore_logo.jpg"]]; , but it's only showing the placeholder ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the right way

```
//cell image set
    NSString *imageStr = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"thumbnail"];
    NSString *trimmedString = [imageStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *string1=[trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = newImage;
    return cell;
```

i hope it helps you all